# Insertar múltiples datos con GETDATE pero con diferencia de hora

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema a la hora de insertar la fecha porque con GETDATE se inserta la misma fecha con la misma hora pero lo que quería era que la fecha tuviera diferencia en segundos cada dato.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BK_PROD (FECHA_INGRESO, NUMERO_PRODUCTO)
  SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 20) AS FECHA_INGRESO,
    P.NUMERO_PRODUCTO
  FROM dbo.PROD AS P,
       dbo.I_PROD AS I
  WHERE P.NUMERO_PRODUCTO = I.NUMERO_PRODUCTO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y qué dato debería ser el primero?, cuánta diferencia de tiempo entre cada fila?

Comment: el primer dato que se inserte va ser el primero porque las tablas del select ya están ordenadas, un segundo de diferencia.

Comment: pero sin `ORDER BY` no hay un `SELECT` ordenado por definición. Por lo tanto necesitaríamos el criterio de ordenación para poder responder correctamente tu duda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola no se si exista una forma mas facil pero yo haria un cursor y luego por cada registro agregaria un segundo

```
DECLARE @FECHA_INGRESO DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @NUMERO_PRODUCTO VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SegundosAdicionales INT = 0;


DECLARE MiCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
    P.NUMERO_PRODUCTO
  FROM dbo.PROD AS P,
       dbo.I_PROD AS I
  WHERE P.NUMERO_PRODUCTO = I.NUMERO_PRODUCTO

OPEN MiCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM MiCursor INTO  @NUMERO_PRODUCTO
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    INSERT INTO BK_PROD (FECHA_INGRESO, NUMERO_PRODUCTO)
    VALUES(DATEADD(ss, @SegundosAdicionales, @FECHA_INGRESO),  @NUMERO_PRODUCTO)

    --Sumamaos 1 segunto para el siguiente registro
    SET @SegundosAdicionales = @SegundosAdicionales + 1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM  MiCursor INTO   @NUMERO_PRODUCTO
END 

CLOSE MiCursor 
DEALLOCATE MiCursor
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si me sirve muchas gracias, pero si es bastante líneas de SQL.